# Openssl write BIO changed after SSL_do_handshake

Tags: openssl

```
  ......
  SSL_set_bio(mSsl, rbio, wbio);
  ......
  BIO* rBio0 = SSL_get_rbio(mSsl);
  BIO* wBio0 = SSL_get_wbio(mSsl);
  printf("xxxxxxxxxxx get0 write %p\n", wBio0);
  printf("xxxxxxxxxxx get0 read %p\n", rBio0);
  int r = SSL_do_handshake(mSsl);
  BIO* rBio1 = SSL_get_rbio(mSsl);
  BIO* wBio1 = SSL_get_wbio(mSsl);
  printf("xxxxxxxxxxx get1 write %p\n", wBio1);
  printf("xxxxxxxxxxx get1 read %p\n", rBio1);
```

This 2 bio is generated using `BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())`, After run the compiled code containing this snippet, the following printed out in my terminal:

```
xxxxxxxxxxx get0 write 0xc18800
xxxxxxxxxxx get0 read 0xc16730
xxxxxxxxxxx get1 write 0xc27f80
xxxxxxxxxxx get1 read 0xc16730
```

Is this normal?

After this snippet, I want to use `BIO_get_mem_data` to get data from memory and send it to remote, because the write bio changed, I can't get data.

BTW, I used to 2 global variable to store write bio and read bio before, all works well.

Comment: May I ask why do you call `SSL_do_handshake` ? Why don't you just connect using appropriate ssl functions and receive/send data ? If you did that would would have no problems with your BIOs.

Comment: I'm implementing dtls-srtp using libnice and openssl, so after the ice connection is ready, I use libnice to send and receive data including dtls handshake data, So I use a memory bio as an intermedia.